# foreach two arrays with replacing ones items with others

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, preg-match-all

Lets say I have two arrays got from pre_gmatch:

```
preg_match_all('#<div class="cloud_flow_big">(.*?)</div>#is', $mystring, $names, PREG_SET_ORDER);
preg_match_all('#<div class="bgframe(.*?)</div></div>#is', $mystring, $numbers, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Items count in gotten arrays is always the same. So here is the code to get what is going on, and there is one repetitive word in all items of first array (this word is **number** in this case):

```
foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
    $i++;
$nameclean = str_replace ("number", $numbers[$key], $names[$key]);
echo $nameclean;
}
```

So how to foreach first array, but in result to replace needed word in 1st array with the needed item from array 2. Example: Word **number** in 1st item from array $names should be replaced with first item from array $numbers

Comment: Can you show us what $mystring, $names, and $numbers are? It's hard to visualize what you're trying to do.

Comment: $mystring is website content I'm getting via curl function
Those strings are allways variable, one thing in common is that all items of first string ($names) contains one same word, and first and second strings item count is allways the same.

Comment: `preg_match_all()` would set your match to a multidimensional array, so `$names[$key]` and `$numbers[$key]` are still arrays, thus `str_replace` would fail. Also, a common recommendation would be "don't use regex to 'interpret' HTML content".

Comment: Ok, so any advice how to convert those multidimensional arrays to simple ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify this a bit and take the preg_match out of the equation. We will simply start with two separate arrays.

```
$numbers = array(
  "I like having number eyes.",
  "there are number days in a week,",
  "A car normally has number wheels.",
);

$names = array( "two", "seven", "four");
```

Answering your question using a foreach, you could do the following

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
  $numbers[$i] = str_replace ("number", $names[$i], $number);
  $i++;
}
```

This however would work better in a for loop instead

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
  $numbers[$i] = str_replace ("number", $names[$i], $numbers[$i]);
}
```

The result of both of these is

```
Array
(
    [0] => I like having two eyes.
    [1] => there are seven days in a week,
    [2] => A car normally has four wheels.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling first **array_replace ()** to replace the values of first array with those in second array will do what you want.

Hope this helps.